# Angularjs in rails: angularjs javascripts don't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want use angularjs in rails. for this, I want deactive rails view and just use angularjs html file. I use `angular-resource.min.js` for routing the url and then I create `index` action in my `application_controller` for deactiving the rails views. Rails view are deactive now, but none of scripts and angular file run in project and when server is start, I see a blanck page, html of this page is empty and javascripts doesn't load in page.

I have below code in this project:

`Forums_controller.rb`:

```
class ForumsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :json
end
```

`comments_controller.rb`:

```
class CommentsController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  respond_to :json
end
```

`application_controller`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def index
    render :layout => 'application', :nothing => true
  end
end
```

`config/rootes.rb`:

```
Simpleforum::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :forums, :defaults => {format: :json} do
    resources :comments, :defaults => {format: :json}
  end
  root to: 'application#index'
end
```

And I add all angularjs requirements to assets folder.

I use this gem:

```
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem 'angularjs-rails-resource', '~> 1.1.1'
```

`angularjs app controller`:

`app.js.erb`:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/',          {controller: 'ForumIndexController',    templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/index.html') %>'})
                    .when('/forum/new', {controller: 'ForumCreateController',   templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/new.html') %>'})
                    .when('/forum/:id', {controller: 'ForumShowController',     templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/show.html') %>'})
                    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        }
        ]);
```

`application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angularjs/rails/resource
//= require angularjs/rails/resource/extensions/snapshots
//= require angular.min
//= require angular-resource.min
//= require ../angular/app
//= require_tree ../angular
```

Where is the problem? How can I fixed this error?

`Note`: I use [this tutorial](http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/ruby-on-rails-angularjs-resources/) for create this project.

Comment: angular-route.js should be used for ruting the url

Comment: My problem is: javascripts don't load. How can I laod all of scripts in my page when I use `render :layout => 'application', :nothing => true` in my `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: faced the same problem and found no solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would change in the `assets/javascript/application.js` :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular.min        <-----------(*)
//= require angularjs/rails/resource
//= require angularjs/rails/resource/extensions/snapshots
//= require angular-resource.min
//= require ../angular/app
//= require_tree ../angular
```

I had a similar `problem` and this the way I fixed it